# I need help writing a text style version of hangman

Tags: python, text

I am supposed to write a text style version of hangman and I am completely lost starting at the first few steps. I need to print/output a number of spaces or underscores ("*") that matches the same number of letters in the phrase chose, for example "the sky is blue" - "* _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _" the code I have now is what my teacher had given me but I'm so lost.

```
cont = "y"
while cont == "y":
    phraselist = hangman()
    r = random.randint(0, len(phraselist)-1)
    phrase = phraselist[r]
    letters = list(phrase)
    print(phrase)
    u = []
    c = 0
    while c < len(letters):
        (u.append("_"))
        c = c + 1
```

Comment: i also have a phrase text file with a list of phrases

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.